# file is not loaded using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a file called external.html,

```
<div id="externDiv">
   <b>This is external content</b>
</div>
```

in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
  <head>  
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="extern.js">  </script>  
 </head>  
 <body>  

 <div id = "externDiv">
  </div>
   <button >hello</button>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

this is extern.js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('button').click(function(){
        $('#externDiv').load('external.html');

       });  

     });
```

but file is not loaded... what should i do? please

Comment: no element in html with `id="t"` ... please clarify target for `load()`

Comment: I don't see any element with `t` ID in your example

Comment: your code is missing `$` near `("#externDiv")`

Answer (score 1):

In a hurry to go over your code? The HTML strcture is not connected to your JavaScript in terms of selectors.

I presume the console will output the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: "#t".load is not a function

Here's the fix:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('button').click(function(){
        $('#externDiv').load('trackingCode.html');
    });  
  });
```

You missed a `$` at `('#t')`